# How to omit some text from regex group in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

`let regexp = /(\b(."https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-"A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i`

`` let stringData = `<p><a href="https://domainName.com/chat/conversationId">https://dev.uniteliving.com/chat/bk7RELvbh7KrvJ6ii#</a>`; ``

Here matching `="https` this string and group `="https://domainName.com/chat/conversationId`.

I want to omit `="` from the group.
Actually need to `https://domainName.com/chat/conversationId`.

Please any body suggest me. How to solved it?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rGSZiu/3)

Comment: Perhaps `['"]((?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-"A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])` See https://regex101.com/r/HlAzH2/1

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

`/(\b((?<=")https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-"A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i`

[Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ee6msJ/2)

What I changed is use a lookbehind `(?<=")` instead of a simple match for this character `"` you don't want.

The original regex was also trying to match "any" character before the `"`, I removed this as I don't think it is useful (at least it's not necessayr with your example).

Comment: thanks your reply. But that checked. I'm comparing two strings 
```href="https://domainName.com/chat/conversationId">https://dev.uniteliving.com/chat/bk7RELvbh7KrvJ6ii#</a>``` vs ```url('https://domainName.com/chat/conversationId')```

Comment: @MasumBillah I'm not sure to understand. Did the answer help, or is it missing something?

Comment: @MasumBillah if you mean you don't want `url("http://some.com")` to match you can use this `(\b((?<=href=")https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-"A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])` . Maybe add your test strings and required matches to help understand your requirements.